# Java can't find file when running through Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, file, exception, filereader

When I run a Java application that should be reading from a file in Eclipse, I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`, even though the file is in the correct directory.  I can compile and run the application from the command line just fine; the problem only occurs in Eclipse, with more than one project and application.  Is there a setting I need to change in the run configurations or build paths to get it to find the file correctly?

Comment: without seeing your code, we can't tell you what might be going on

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem is most likely that your application is using a relative pathname.  As @BalusC says, relative pathnames can be problematic.  But IMO, he goes way too far when he says *"[y]ou should **never** use relative paths in java.io  stuff"*.

When an application opens a file using (for example) the `FileInputStream(File)` constructor, relative pathnames are resolved relative to the "current directory" in a process described as follows in the javadoc for [`File.getAbsolutePath()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()).

> [...] Otherwise this pathname is resolved in a system-dependent way. On UNIX systems, a relative pathname is made absolute by resolving it against the current user directory. On Microsoft Windows systems, a relative pathname is made absolute by resolving it against the current directory of the drive named by the pathname, if any; if not, it is resolved against the current user directory.

So immediately, we see that the notion of "current directory" has different nuances on Windows and UNIX platforms.  The second issue is that in pure Java you cannot definitively find out what the current directory is, and you certainly cannot change it for the current JVM using pure Java.  (When the JVM starts, the "user.dir" system property is set to the current directory, but *there is nothing stopping an application from changing the property* so you cannot entirely rely on it.  Furthermore, changing "user.dir" only changes the way that the empty path is resolved, not relative paths in general.)

So what should you do about this?

- One option is to use absolute pathnames to refer to files.  This is reliable in (almost) all cases, but using absolute pathnames can be problematic if the user has to enter the pathname, or
  if you need to avoid hard-wired (or configured) absolute pathnames.
- A second option is to use classpath relative pathnames and locate files relative to the application's installation directory.  This works if that is what you need to do, but presents a problem if you need to pass a `File` to some library method.  It also doesn't help if you are trying to find the user's application preferences.  (In general, putting user preferences into the installation directory is a mistake ...)
- A third option is to name a file relative to some absolute directory that you get from somewhere else; e.g. `new File(System.getProperty("home.dir"), "foo/bar");`.
- The final option is to use relative pathnames, and assume that the user knowing what the current directory.  For many applications that the user runs from the command line, this is the right solution.

In the particular case of Eclipse, there is a simple solution.  Go to the "run configuration" that you are using to launch your application, open the "Arguments" tab, and click the "Other" radio button.  Then enter an absolute pathname as the working directory for the launched application.  When the child JVM is launched, it will have the specified working directory as its current directory.

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to simply figure out what directory the "current path" points to in your environment -- whatever that is.  Once you figure out, you can choose your solution from there.  Maybe that is to use an appropriate relative path to your file's location or relocating the file.

```
    File testFile = new File("");
    String currentPath = testFile.getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println("current path is: " + currentPath);
```

Comment: This isn't ideal in shipping code, but it's definitely useful as debug code to see what your application thinks is going on.

Answer (score 7):

When you create a default Java application in Eclipse, you get this directory structure:

**./ProjectName/** - root directory
**./ProjectName/bin/** - output directory, containing .class files
**./ProjectName/src/** - source directory, containing .java files

If your application requests "./data.txt" it will search for it relative to the root directory.  This is the "working directory" and can be configured in the arguments tab as per Martin's reply above.

You say it works from the command line?  This is likely because you're inside either the bin or src folders when you run the java binary.  The working directory in this case is whichever directory the command prompt is currently inside.  If, for example, you go into the /src/ directory, say `javac *.java` then run the files from there, it will search for "./data.txt" within the /src/ directory.  If you go inside the /bin/ directory and run your application from there, it will look for the file relative to the /bin/ directory.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The text files I need do exist in the /bin/ directory, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.  I'll play around with relative paths and see what I can get.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem , I placed my files in a folder named cobolcopybooks inside the src folder and tried to access them inside my project using classloader.getResource("cobolcopybooks/demostud.cob")
but i was getting null pointer exception,i tried it several times by cleaning and building the workspaces after several failed attempts i realised  that i was not refreshing the project to allow the files to get built along with the project. i.e these files should be visible along with other class files as at runtime the root directory will be bin directory and it's searching for those files there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the user does not enter the full file path to the file
and enter something like "myfilenameonly".
`File file = new File(".", args[0])` is necessary in this case to
locate the file (paying attention to the first argument passed).

All platforms: `File.getParent()` does not return the parent directory,
it should return ".." or the name of the parent directory in a file-system
specific way.

If you create the File "myfilenameonly"  without specifying the full path
to the directory where it is located, the `File.getParent()`, for example,
will return null.

See further: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=1228537