# JSP: FileReader with relative path throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have some embedded Java code in which I'm trying to load a properties file that is located in the same folder as the JSP file:

```
Properties titles = new Properties();
titles.load(new FileReader("titles.txt"));
```

The code above throws a FileNotFoundException.

How exactly does one refer to the 'current folder' in this situation?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792870/java-cant-find-file-when-running-through-eclipse/2792939#2792939

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

1. JSPs should not contain java code. use an mvc framework (spring mvc, stripes etc) as controller and use the JSP as view only. That makes life a lot easier
2. You are not supposed to access resource files through the file system in a web app, use classloader access [as suggested by redlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108671/jsp-filereader-with-relative-path-throws-filenotfoundexception/3108720#3108720). The problem is that a web app may or may not be unpacked on the file system, that's up to the servlet container

The main problem I see is that you can't make any valid assumptions as to what the path is, as you don't know where your compiled JSPs are

So: create a controller class, put the properties file in the same folder and load it from the controller class via `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("titles.txt");`

Comment: yes I was thinking of that too, it could be a problem that JSP are compiled and the resource would not be found.
And your of course totally right on point 1!!!

Answer (score 3):

`FileReader` requires absolute path, or relative the where the java is run. But for web applications this is usually done via `/etc/init.d/tomcat startup` and you can't rely on what is the current dir.

You can obtain the absolute path of your application by calling `servletContext.getRealPath("/relative/path/to/file.txt")`

You can get the relative part of the URL by calling `request.getRequestURL()`.

That said, you'd better use this code in a servlet, not a JSP - JSP is a view technology and logic should not be placed in it.

Comment: FileReader requires absolute path'. No it doesn't. The issue here is that the current directory when executing a JSP isn't determined by any attribute of the JSP itself, so locating the file relative to the JSP is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

By using the classloader that loads your class you can get the file easily.

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("titles.txt");
```

However I don't know if it will work with JSP

You could also use `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream("")`, but then you have to give the <strike>full</strike> webcontent-relative path.

Comment: The last is not true. It just accepts a webcontent-relative path.